# How to do string interpolation in rails config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the rails config gem to feed external urls into my application. I would like to do parameter interpolation in the following manner:

settings.yml

```
url: 'http://www.example.com/#{self.param}'
```

then in model.rb:

```
def get_path
    magic(Settings.url) #some magic procedure or function here
end
```

When I call get path I would like to have the fully interpolated url. Is there some "magic" function or method that would allow me to do that with [railsconfig](https://github.com/railsconfig)? I would prefer something safer than passing the string into an eval call.

Comment: Use double quotes, not single quotes, for string interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following method:

settings.yml:

```
url: 'http://www.example.com/%{param}'
```

model.rb:

```
def get_path
    Settings.url % {param: self.param}
end
```

which properly returns the current value of param interpolated into the string when model#get_path is called.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `self.param` interpreted at runtime when `get_path` is invoked, you could use ERB to parse the result.  For example:

```
require 'erb'

def get_path(url, param)
  bar = "1"
  ERB.new(url).result(binding)
end

url = "http://www.example.com/<%= param %>?bar=<%= bar %>"
param = "foo"
puts get_path(url, param)
```

Would yield:

```
http://www.example.com/foo?bar=1
```